# graphQl mutation query not working with variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I am new to graphql and just not getting any flow how to run this mutation query with variabls.
please help me out.

```
mutation SignupUser($signupData : SignupInput) {
      signupUser(signupData: {username: $username, password: $password, email: $email, firstname: $firstname, lastname: $lastname, shareRateCards: $shareRateCards, freeTrial: $freeTrial, termsOfAgreement:$termsOfAgreement, clientId: $clientId }) {
      user {
      firstName
      lastName
      email
      shareRateCards
      freeTrial
      termsOfAgreement
      clientId
      username}
      }
      }


    let variables = {
       username: this.username,
       password: this.password,
       email: this.email,
       firstname: this.firstname,
       lastname: this.lastname,
       shareRateCards: true, 
       freeTrial: true, 
       termsOfAgreement: true, 
       clientId:5
    };
```

please let me know how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the mutation to:

```js
gql`
mutation SignupUser($signupData: SignupInput) {
  signupUser(signupData: $signupData) {
    user {
      firstName
      lastName
      email
      shareRateCards
      freeTrial
      termsOfAgreement
      clientId
      username
    }
  }
}`
```

And on the server you define the  mutation like:

```js
`mutation signupUser(signupData: SignupInput): User`


// resolver:

signupUser(_, { signupData }) {
  // return user
}
```

Comment: I resolved the issue, was giving one wrong field name. Thanks for the reply btw.